# Does browser cache blob src?

Tags: javascript, html, video.js, src, brightcove

I'm using videoJS to play my videos which are hosted on Brightcove. I just give it a videoId and it automatically fetches the src which I guess gets translated into a   blob src like `src="blob:https://crap.crap"`.

However, it seems like when I remove the `<video>` component then put it back, the video gets refetched from the source and I'm not sure if the browser cached it or not. Does anyone know if it's possible to manually cache a `blob` src?

**edit**: It is streamed via this protocol

Comment: no, blobs are unique each time they are created. the underlying http-based hls files might reside in the http cache however, so don't be surprised if you see warm-cache load times, as in-computer lag between caches is minimal.

Comment: So for brightcove videos, I just set a `data-video-id` value on the `<video>` element which then gets translated to a src when I call `bc(myVideoElement)`. I guess it looks it up on their server. The video element then get's a `blob` src (haven't confirmed this is the case for all browsers/devices). VideoJs actually has a function to get the actual source of the video which comes back as a `.m3u8` in my case (again, not sure if that's for all browsers). I guess I can just cache that source and set it directly on the video element the next time I want to play the video.

Comment: What are the caching headers of the response, btw?

Comment: @9000 on each segment*.ts file I see the header `Cache-Control: public, max-age=31118785`

Comment: If you created a URL from the blob using `URL.createObjectURL()` then it does cache it for the lifetime of the window being open and you should call `URL.revokeObjectURL()` to release the memory.